# Black card ability - all players exile a creature - does it work on the one with protection from black

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

Let's assume I have black card with "player must exile a creature" and one of mine opponents have only one creature on the battlefield, but it has "protection from black".

Does mine card affect his?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. Your card does not target the creature, so its protection ability does not help here.

Remember that protection can be summarized with the [mnemonic acronym DEBT](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Protection):

> The object with protection cannot be:
>
> - Damaged by sources with the specified quality. (All such damage is prevented.)
> - Enchanted or equipped by permanents with the specified quality.
> - Blocked by creatures with the specified quality.
> - Targeted by spells with the specified quality, or by abilities from sources of that quality.

Your card might target the player but it'll never target the creature directly.